# Disqus-like comment thread logic in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, foreach

I'm trying to make a commenting thread like Disqus has done. I'm having trouble setting up the logic in PHP to display the comments such that one can reply to each comment and those comments will then stay attached to each other.

here's my MySQL comments table:

```
comment_id  comment  item_id  replied_to_id  time
 1           hello1    1          1         1:00pm
 2           hello2    1          1         2:00pm
 3           hello3    1          3         3:00pm
 4           hello4    2          4         4:00pm
 5           hello5    1          2         2:00pm
 6           hello6    1          3         6:00pm
```

`item_id` is a column which indicates the parent item that the comments are discussing.

If I pull from my database all the comments with `item_id=1`, then I'm not sure how to thread them such that the `comment_id` and `replied_to_id`'s are appropriately matched. For example, `comment_id=2` should be matched to `comment_id=1`.

Here's my PHP:

```
<?foreach($comments as $row){
  if($row->comment_id==$row->replied_to_id){
    echo $row->comment."-".$row->time; //desired output: hello1-1:00pm    
      foreach($comments as $sub_row){
        if($row->comment_id!=$sub_row->replied_to_id){
           echo $sub_row->comment."-".$sub_row->time;// desired output: hello2-2:00pm
             foreach($comments as $sub_sub_row){
                if($row->comment_id!=$sub_sub_row->replied_to_id){
                  echo $sub_sub_row->comment."-".$sub_sub_row->time;// desired output: hello5-5:00pm  
                }
             } 
        }
     }          
  }
  else{
    echo $row->comment."-".$row->time;   // desired output: hello3-3:00pm
  }
}
```

This just looks wrong. There has got to be a better way to do this.

Comment: The magic keyword is *recursion*. For which, of course, you first have to understand recursion... :o)

Comment: thanks Deceze, i thought recursion would be the key but just not sure how to set up a simple demo based on my parameters. Might you be able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple demo, not necessarily the most optimal, but working:

```
function displayComments(array $comments, $parentId = null) {
    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
        if ($comment['replied_to_id'] == $parentId) {
            echo $comment['comment'];
            displayComments($comments, $comment['id']);
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes top-level comments have no `replied_to_id` (`null`). Your example with comment `1` replying to `1` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: thanks! yes, comment `1` replying to `1` makes no sense, was more just for my bookkeeping. If it is easier for you to make the recursion example without this, I would greatly appreciate to see what that would look like too. thanks,

Comment: Uhm, sorry? The example given above demonstrates recursion to output threaded comments, ignoring the current `1` = `1` and instead assuming comment `1` has a `replied_to_id` of `null`.

Comment: one other thing is i'm using codeigniter and their `foreach` shorthand: `<? foreach(...):?>`. I'm not sure how to wrap that code in your `displayComments()` function. The reason i'm using this shorthand is because in reality i'm not just doing a simple `echo $comment`, there is quite a bit of HTML that's being rendered.

Comment: `<? foreach (..): ?>` is perfectly fine alternative PHP syntax and has nothing to do with CI. You can run the above perfectly fine in CI. You should probably put the function into a helper instead of a view template, but the idea is the same. And yes, your real code will probably be more complicated, but the point is to get you to understand recursion. You can work the rest out yourself.

Comment: thanks, one last thing if possible? I was unsure from your comment if  your recursion demo will produce **ALL** of the desired output I specified above? Or would it be restricted to comments where `comment_id!=replied_to_id`?

Comment: hi deceze, i reproduced your example exactly but can't get it to work as an `object` or `array`. I also changed `['id']` to `['comment_id']` and `['item_id']`, but no luck. Would you mind double checking to see if there is something not quite right/oversimplified? thanks,

Comment: OK, you need to understand the logic. Calling `displayComments($comments)` first finds and outputs the first comment whose `replied_to_id` is `null` (or `1` or whatever you pass as the second parameter). Having found that, it will call itself as `displayComment($comments, 1)`, outputting the first comment whose `replied_to_id` is `1`, then calling itself as `displayComment($comments, 2)`, outputting all comments whose `replied_to_id` is `2` etc etc recursively...

Comment: hi deceze, I started a new question because I couldn't figure out how to put a view file inside your `displayComments()` function. Would you mind looking at this 2nd comment I posed to help out with that syntax?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10378860/load-a-view-file-within-a-function-in-php-codeigniter   Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is all very new territory for me, thank you,