# load a view file within a function in php/codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a function that I'd like plug a view file. It's pretty simple when you just need to `echo` one or two things but I have some complicated html and so would like to take advantage of alternate php syntax for the following foreach loop and if statements:

**UPDATE** I corrected the `CI->load->view` to include the 3rd parameter according to tpaksu's suggestion. It's closer to working but still not quite right. See comments below in the code:

```
<?
  function displayComments(array $comments, $parentId = null) {
  $CI=& get_instance();     
  foreach($comments as $comment){
        if($comment['replied_to_id'] == $parentId){

     echo $CI->load->view('reviews/comment_list', $comments, true); // this doesn't work, it only shows the last array member
              // echo $comment['comment']; this works as expected
    }
   }
  }  
displayComments($comments, $parentId = null);        
?>
```

Here's what the 'reviews/comment list view file looks like in its simplest form:

```
<ul> 
 <? foreach($comments as $comment): $comment=$comment['comment']?>
  <li>
      <?echo $comment?>
 </li> 
 <?endforeach;>
</ul>
```

Would anyone know to how embed view files into a function?

Comment: is the `reviews/comment_list` view parsing all of the comments, or just one comment?

Comment: its parsing all the comments, it's like this: `<ul> <? foreach($comments as $comment): $comment=$comment['comment']?><li><?echo $comment?></li> <?endforeach;></ul>`.

Comment: ok, if it's parsing all the comments, why are you still using the foreach?

Comment: i knew that wasn't right, it's just that I couldn't get it to show any comments and was getting errors if I didn't define `$comment`

Comment: edited my answer. BTW you forget a "?" after endforeach;

Comment: thanks, your updated answer is close but still not perfect, it outputs the entire list 3 times (one for each `replied_to_id's` the last array member has.). I don't think it needs that 2nd foreach loop inside the view file because if you just echo the `$comment` inside the function than it produces the list correctly (i.e., recursively) and only once.

Comment: what second foreach loop? my edited answer has only one foreach loop. I wrote them to replace all of your file contents. how can be there 3 loops if you all wrote it right? The only thing in my answer that could produce that 3x result is only when your $comments array has 3x times of all your data.

Comment: hi tpaksu, the 2 foreach loops are: 1) inside the `displayComments()` and 2) inside the `<ul>`. The "3 loops" is specific to the data I'm using. I only mentioned that it was outputting the list 3 times because that provided a clue as to what was wrong. What is important is that if you uncomment my original code `// echo $comment['comment'];` than the comments print once as expected

Comment: there is no displayComments in my code. As expected.

Comment: hi, i need the `displayComments()` because I need a recursive function to match comments with their replies. Please note the `if($comment['replied_to_id'])...` part of the code. Its not as simple as just listing the comments. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Thats it. I'm done. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use to have a **snippet_helper** in my projects. There, I have many many functions wich generates chunks of reusable things (also called *modules* or *components*).

I do like, also, the WordPress approach wich use to return data in the main function (you may need more treatments before display) and a "sister function" to directly `echo` the results.

I think it'll works with you. For example:

```
function get_display_comments(array $comments, $parentId = NULL)
{
    $CI     =& get_instance();
    $return = '';

    foreach ($comments AS $comment)
    {
        if ($comment['replied_to_id'] == $parentId)
        {
            $return .= $CI->load->view('reviews/comment_list', $comments, TRUE);
        }
    }

    return $return;
}

function display_comments(array $comments, $parentId = NULL)
{
    echo get_display_comments($comments, $parentId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your content on the first file :

```
<?php
    $CI=& get_instance();     
    echo $CI->load->view('reviews/comment_list', $comments, true);
?>
```

And the `reviews/comment_list` view :

```
<ul> 
    <?php
    foreach($comments as $comment){
       $comment=$comment['comment'];
       echo "<li>" . $comment . "</li>";
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

just write this and try again.

Comment: hi tpaksu, thanks. do I use `$CI` or `$this` inside the function?

Comment: thanks Ben, hmm, i can't get the entire array to display from the view file. Its only printing the last comment in the array. Any obvious reason for this? I'm loading the $comments into the view file like this: `$this->load->view('myfile', $comments, true);`

Comment: first, are you using 'myfile' or 'reviews/comments_list'? second, it seems like a problem in your comments_list view.

Comment: hi tpaksu, i'm using 'reviews/comments_list'. hmm i'm trying to render something simple within 'reviews/comments_list' to troubleshoot. Have any thoughts on why its only showing the last array row?

Comment: are you still using the outside loop? Please edit your question and add the last version of the code.